# Need help on how to let user input a list of numbers

Tags: list, user-input

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
c = []
for i in a:
    if i < b:
        c.append(i)
print(c)
```

Need help I want to allow the user to input their own list of numbers instead of the pre written list in a, i'm sorry if my post is confusing i'm new to coding and this is my first time using stack overflow.
the code is written in Python

Comment: Hope this helps. See this guide: https://www.edureka.co/blog/input-a-list-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Loop For Multiple Inputs Of Data From User

loop:
input

Comment: Thanks your for replyi

Answer (score 0):

You Have To Try Following Code

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

c = []
for i in a:
 b = int(input("Please enter a number: ")) 
 c.append(b)
print(c)
```